# Apache NiFi 1.5 Failed to Start - Failed to set permissions

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

I've seen this same issue in several different flavors.  The solutions posted however either have nothing to do with my issue or there is simply no solution posted at all.

`Apache Nifi 1.5`

`Java JDK 9.0.4` - Is this version supported by NiFi?

`JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4`

I had an idea that perhaps Apache NiFi doesn't work with JDK version 9.0.4 however I am unable to find any documentation that states what version of JDK Apache NiFi is compatible with and so my assumption is that it doesn't matter.

From what I can see in the `nifi-app.log` and the `nifi-bootstrap.log` files have Warnings and Errors all related to 'Permissions'.  Another possible cause (guessing) could be the due to the `security properties` in the `nifi.properties` file.  I have set the `nifi.sensitive.propr.key` however I see another attribute that I did not set: `nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected`.

I've placed below the contents of both of the log files as there is nothing in the `nifi-user.log` file:

#### nifi-app.log

```
2018-03-20 14:29:01,599 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Launching NiFi...
2018-03-20 14:29:01,795 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Determined default nifi.properties path to be 'C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf\nifi.properties'
2018-03-20 14:29:01,799 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Loaded 144 properties from C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf\nifi.properties
2018-03-20 14:29:01,806 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Loaded 144 properties
2018-03-20 14:29:01,902 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Started Bootstrap Listener, Listening for incoming requests on port 50794
2018-03-20 14:29:01,920 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Successfully initiated communication with Bootstrap
2018-03-20 14:29:01,941 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarUnpacker Expanding 89 NAR files with all processors...
2018-03-20 14:29:06,675 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarUnpacker NAR loading process took 4734149236 nanoseconds (4 seconds).
2018-03-20 14:29:07,889 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: stackoverflow text removed due to 30000 char limit
2018-03-20 14:29:07,905 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,907 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,910 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,914 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,916 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,917 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,920 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,923 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,924 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,927 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,930 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,933 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,936 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,938 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,945 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,948 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,949 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,950 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,951 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,952 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,953 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,954 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,955 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,956 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,958 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,959 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,960 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,961 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,962 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,963 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,964 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,965 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,966 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,968 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,969 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,971 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,971 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,972 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,973 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,977 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,980 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,982 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,983 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,989 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,990 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,992 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,997 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,998 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:07,998 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,001 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,002 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,002 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,002 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,004 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,005 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,006 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,008 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,009 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,010 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,011 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,012 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,014 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,016 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,017 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,018 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,019 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,020 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,021 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,021 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,022 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,023 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,024 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,026 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,028 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,029 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,031 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,032 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,033 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,035 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,036 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,037 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,038 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,042 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,043 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,050 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,053 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,061 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: ""
2018-03-20 14:29:08,062 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: stackoverflow text removed due to 30000 char limit
2018-03-20 14:29:08,209 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log Logging initialized @7174ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2018-03-20 14:29:08,278 INFO [main] o.a.n.w.s.HostHeaderSanitizationCustomizer Created HostHeaderSanitizationCustomizer for :9090
2018-03-20 14:29:08,278 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Added HostHeaderSanitizationCustomizer to HttpConfiguration: HostHeaderSanitizationCustomizer for :9090
2018-03-20 14:29:08,278 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Configuring Jetty for HTTP on port: 9090
2018-03-20 14:29:08,410 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading WAR: C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\extensions\nifi-standard-nar-1.5.0.nar-unpacked\META-INF\bundled-dependencies\nifi-jolt-transform-json-ui-1.5.0.war with context path set to /nifi-jolt-transform-json-ui-1.5.0
2018-03-20 14:29:08,410 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading UI extension [ProcessorConfiguration, /nifi-jolt-transform-json-ui-1.5.0] for org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON:org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-nar:1.5.0
2018-03-20 14:29:08,413 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading WAR: C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\extensions\nifi-media-nar-1.5.0.nar-unpacked\META-INF\bundled-dependencies\nifi-image-viewer-1.5.0.war with context path set to /nifi-image-viewer-1.5.0
2018-03-20 14:29:08,415 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading WAR: C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\extensions\nifi-update-attribute-nar-1.5.0.nar-unpacked\META-INF\bundled-dependencies\nifi-update-attribute-ui-1.5.0.war with context path set to /nifi-update-attribute-ui-1.5.0
2018-03-20 14:29:08,416 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading UI extension [ProcessorConfiguration, /nifi-update-attribute-ui-1.5.0] for org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute:org.apache.nifi:nifi-update-attribute-nar:1.5.0
2018-03-20 14:29:08,418 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading WAR: C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\extensions\nifi-standard-nar-1.5.0.nar-unpacked\META-INF\bundled-dependencies\nifi-standard-content-viewer-1.5.0.war with context path set to /nifi-standard-content-viewer-1.5.0
2018-03-20 14:29:08,419 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading WAR: C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\framework\nifi-framework-nar-1.5.0.nar-unpacked\META-INF\bundled-dependencies\nifi-web-ui-1.5.0.war with context path set to /nifi
2018-03-20 14:29:08,420 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading WAR: C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\framework\nifi-framework-nar-1.5.0.nar-unpacked\META-INF\bundled-dependencies\nifi-web-api-1.5.0.war with context path set to /nifi-api
2018-03-20 14:29:08,421 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading WAR: C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\framework\nifi-framework-nar-1.5.0.nar-unpacked\META-INF\bundled-dependencies\nifi-web-content-viewer-1.5.0.war with context path set to /nifi-content-viewer
2018-03-20 14:29:08,423 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading WAR: C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\framework\nifi-framework-nar-1.5.0.nar-unpacked\META-INF\bundled-dependencies\nifi-web-docs-1.5.0.war with context path set to /nifi-docs
2018-03-20 14:29:08,441 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading documents web app with context path set to /nifi-docs
2018-03-20 14:29:08,447 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading WAR: C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\framework\nifi-framework-nar-1.5.0.nar-unpacked\META-INF\bundled-dependencies\nifi-web-error-1.5.0.war with context path set to /
2018-03-20 14:29:08,471 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.web.server.HostHeaderHandler Created HostHeaderHandler for localhost:9090
2018-03-20 14:29:08,471 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Created HostHeaderHandler [HostHeaderHandler for localhost:9090]
2018-03-20 14:29:08,566 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.nifi.authorization.AccessPolicyProvider: org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider Unable to get public no-arg constructor
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.nifi.authorization.AccessPolicyProvider: org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:672)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.access$1000(ServiceLoader.java:390)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1227)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1259)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1294)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1379)
    at org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager.loadExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager.discoverExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:792)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:160)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:268)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3315)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2108)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:659)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:656)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:667)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
2018-03-20 14:29:08,568 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2018-03-20 14:29:08,569 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).
```

#### nifi-bootstrap.log

```
2018-03-20 14:28:59,621 INFO [main] o.a.n.b.NotificationServiceManager Successfully loaded the following 0 services: []
2018-03-20 14:28:59,625 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STARTED
2018-03-20 14:28:59,625 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STOPPED
2018-03-20 14:28:59,625 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_DIED
2018-03-20 14:29:00,686 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...
2018-03-20 14:29:00,687 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: C:\NIFI-1~1.0
2018-03-20 14:29:00,688 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\java.exe -classpath C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jetty-schemas-3.1.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-api-1.5.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-framework-api-1.5.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-nar-utils-1.5.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-properties-1.5.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-runtime-1.5.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -XX:+UseG1GC -Dnifi.properties.file.path=C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf\nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=50793 -Dapp=NiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=C:\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\\logs org.apache.nifi.NiFi 
2018-03-20 14:29:01,142 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file C:\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\run\nifi.pid; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2018-03-20 14:29:01,146 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read status file C:\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\run\nifi.status; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2018-03-20 14:29:01,148 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 5328
2018-03-20 14:29:01,910 WARN [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file C:\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\run\nifi.pid; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2018-03-20 14:29:01,916 WARN [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read status file C:\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\run\nifi.status; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2018-03-20 14:29:01,918 INFO [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Apache NiFi now running and listening for Bootstrap requests on port 50794
2018-03-20 14:29:09,158 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi NiFi never started. Will not restart NiFi
```

Two main things I see in these log files that I do not fully understand that can perhaps shine some light on my issue:

1. `app.log:` java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.nifi.authorization.AccessPolicyProvider: org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider Unable to get public no-arg constructor
2. `bootstrap log:` Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file

   - Who is the owner?  I'm running as an Admin user.  Is this referring to the Security Settings set on the file for Windows users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue preventing start-up is the error in nifi-app.log related to the access policy provider.

Specifically the root cause of the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
```

This is likely because of this:

[How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j#43574427)

The NiFi Admin Guide - System Requirements state that NiFi needs JDK 8 or newer:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#system-requirements

Technically I believe this should just say JDK 8 since there will have to be some changes to support JDK 9.

Comment: That was it my friend!  Had to install JDK 8.  I don't suppose you know the answer to my secondary question?  Was my assumption correct regarding the NiFi config files?  To avoid the 'Permission' Errors do I need to restrict those files to my specific Windows User?  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @CodeNovice I'm not sure about the second question, personally I have never run on NiFi on Windows so I'm not really familiar with that, although some folks in the community have, you could always try the mailing lists to reach a larger audience

Comment: @CodeNovice Were you able to find the solution to your 2nd question?

Comment: @SagarMorakhia My NiFi still gives that error when it starts.  If you find out what it means or how the files should be properly secured regarding user permissions I would love to know.  If you find the answer, post it here and I'll gladly mark it up as I'm still curious.